# Django upload csv file - only 1st row save in the db.. What could be wrong?

Tags: django, csv, upload

I am creating a django application and I am trying to a upload a csv file, when uploaded, only 1 row is saved. Please find below sample data.

CSV File:

```
first_name, last_name, email, phone, room
Juliet, Tolentino, julz@gmaial.com, 1234567, 13
Jiselle, Buena, jis@gmail.com, 45678899, 14
```

Model:

```
class Teacher(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    room = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/', default='prof_avatar.jpg')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Views

```
def importteacher(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render(request, 'teachers/importteacher.html')

    csv_file = request.FILES['file']

    if not csv_file.name.endswith('.csv'):
        return render(request, 'teachers/importteacher.html',
                      {'form': AuthenticationForm(), 'error': 'The file is not a CSV format'})

    data_set = csv_file.read().decode('UTF-8')
    io_string = io.StringIO(data_set)
    next(io_string)
    for column in csv.reader(io_string, delimiter=','):
        _, created = Teacher.objects.update_or_create(
            first_name=column[0],
            last_name=column[1],
            email=column[2],
            phone=column[3],
            room=column[4]
        )
        context = {}
        return render(request, 'teachers/importteacher.html', context)
```

Form

```
<form  method="POST" ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="row justify-content-center mt-5">
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <h2>Import Teacher</h2>
             <input class="btn btn-primary" type="file" name="file">
             <p>ONLY accepts csv files</p>
             <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Upload</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Thanks.Appreciate your response

Answer (score 0):

You have the `return` line in the for loop, move this line out the loop

```
def importteacher(request):
    ...
    for column in csv.reader(io_string, delimiter=','):
        _, created = Teacher.objects.update_or_create(
            first_name=column[0],
            last_name=column[1],
            email=column[2],
            phone=column[3],
            room=column[4]
        )
    context = {}
    return render(request, 'teachers/importteacher.html', context)
```

Comment: Thank you. Appreciate your time and support.